# Comparing counted up values and only outputting those that have a difference - PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

How can I compare the counts for the below table and only output those that have a difference?

| DOC | VARIABLE | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DOC1 | PSTART | 8 |
| DOC1 | PEND | 8 |
| DOC2 | PSTART | 5 |
| DOC2 | PEND | 6 |
| DOC3 | PSTART | 12 |
| DOC3 | PEND | 12 |

Comment: could you please show also the desired output

Comment: the output would just show 'DOC2' and the counts for 'PSTART' and 'PEND'. 'DOC1' and 'DOC3' would not show on the output.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (doc, variable, cnt) as
  2    (select 'doc1', 'pstart',  8 from dual union all
  3     select 'doc1', 'pend'  ,  8 from dual union all
  4     select 'doc2', 'pstart',  5 from dual union all
  5     select 'doc2', 'pend'  ,  6 from dual union all
  6     select 'doc3', 'pstart', 12 from dual union all
  7     select 'doc3', 'pend'  , 12 from dual
  8    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  9  select doc, sum(case when variable = 'pstart' then cnt end) pstart,
 10              sum(case when variable = 'pend'   then cnt end) pend
 11  from test
 12  group by doc
 13  having sum(case when variable = 'pstart' then cnt end) <>
 14         sum(case when variable = 'pend'   then cnt end);

DOC      PSTART       PEND
---- ---------- ----------
doc2          5          6

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to solve it:

```
 select max(doc),max(variable),"count(*)" from your_table
 group by "count(*)" having count(*)=1
```